# Get specific value from nested collections using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of "product" objects that each contain a collection of benefit objects. See below:

```
<Products>
        <Product ID="454">
            <ProductName>Economy</ProductName>
            <Benefits>
                <Benefit>
                    <Name>Medical</Name>
                    <Value>5000000</Value>
                    <Excess>100</Excess>
                </Benefit>
                <Benefit>
                    <Name>Emergency</Name>
                    <Value>350</Value>
                    <Excess>100</Excess>
                </Benefit>
        </Product>
</Products>
```

I'm trying to create a LINQ query to get the "Medical" benefit value for product "454":

```
<%: Model.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId == "454").SelectMany(p => p.Benefits).Where(b => b.Name == "Medical").Select(v => v.Value.ToString()) %>
```

However this just returns:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Domain.Entities.Benefit,System.String]  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Domain.Entities.Benefit,System.String]  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Domain.Entities.Benefit,System.String]  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Domain.Entities.Benefit,System.String
```

How do I get it to return the actual value I'm after?

Answer (score 4):

If you know there is only one (guaranteed) then add `.Single()` - if there might be none / some and you just want the first, add `.FirstOrDefault()` (will return null if there are no results)

Comment: If the collection might be empty also look into SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Model.Products
    .Where(p => p.ID == 454)
    .SelectMany(p => p.Benefits)
    .Where(b => b.Name == "Medical")
    .Single()
    .Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var val = employees.Where(p => p.ProductId == 454).FirstOrDefault().Benefits.Select(b => b.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var benefits_value = employees.Where(p => p.ProductId == 454).Single().Benefits.Select(b => b.Value).Single();
```